# Best way of cache-management with spring for static files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching, cache-control

I want use cache control in spring mvc for static files.

I have gone through the following scenarios

1. Using WebContentHandlerInterceptor.
2. Using browser cache headers.
3. Using mvc:resources
4. Version number/build number for the js files.

But my problem is when the user comes for the first time it is loaded with the latest static files. If I update any JS files that are needed to be updated in the test or production server before the cache expiration. The browser is taking only from cache until I reload using F5 or Ctrl+F5.

When the user is requested a page, then all static files are to be checked and if they are not modified then it has to use cache otherwise take the latest one from the server.

Please help me.. I am newbee to this stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure browser to download the latest version of your static files is to add a parameter to the URL.

For example, your request will look like `resources/scripts/menu.js?ver=1.0`.